# Elasticsearch exact match of specific field(s)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, exact-match

I'm trying to filter my elasticsearch index by specific fields, the "country" field to be exact. However, I keep getting loads of other results (other countries) back that are not exact.

Please could someone point me in the right direction.

I've tried the following searches:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/decision/council/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "country": "Algeria"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example document:

```
{
  "_index": "decision",
  "_id": "54290140ec882c6dac5ae9dd",
  "_score": 1,
  "_type": "council",
  "_source": {
    "document": "DEV DOCUMENT"
    "id": "54290140ec882c6dac5ae9dd",
    "date_updated": 1396448966,
    "pdf_file": null,
    "reported": true,
    "date_submitted": 1375894031,
    "doc_file": null,
    "country": "Algeria"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by results that are not exact?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @femtoRgon So I want the search to *only* return documents with the field "country": "Algeria" - however, if I run the searches I've been doing it returns documents with all different countries such as "country": "Sri Lanka".

Comment: Okay, that doesn't seem to make much sense.  Can you run [an explain query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html), to see where it is finding a match for those documents?

Comment: @femtoRgon - I added: "explain": true, - above the "query" in the search - the output shows no difference to when it is not present.

Comment: Interestingly if I do a search like this: http://127.0.0.1:9200/decision/council/_search?q=country:Algeria' it returns the right results... how? why?

Comment: Can you post the mapping for your index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the match_phrase query instead

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/decision/council/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match_phrase" : { "country" : "Algeria"}
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - just tried the above, still returns other countries.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Post not GET

Comment: not exactly what I need: it will return if one or more words match, e.g. both `old titl` and `old title1` with match to `old title`